# PHP: How to sort 5 specific values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array. It looks like this:

```
[1=Name][2=Type][3=Company][4=State][5=Date]

[6=Name][7=Type][8=Company][9=State][10=Date]

[11=Name][12=Type][13=Company][14=State][15=Date]
```

Now I want to sort every 5 values in A-Z order by their names. So `[1=Name][2=Type][3=Company][4=State][5=Date]` would be considered one line that needs to be sorted, and `[6=Name][7=Type][8=Company][9=State][10=Date]` would be considered a second line. And they need to be sorted by their names, `[1]` & `[6]`...

I've never encountered such a case, hence I struggling to find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Iterate the array and use array_slice() function http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php to sort each "row/line" of the array.

Comment: Unless you are getting this array from somewhere else, you should considering using a matrix (i.e., an array of array) or an array of objects to hold that data. That will greatly simply your model and any code you will do to process it, including sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear please provide some clear examples of expected outputs. Whatever I understood you can try code like this:

```
$arr=array("1" => "name1", "2" => "game4", "3" => "game10", "4" => "game2",
   "5" => "game3", "6" => "name4", "7" => "game4", "8" => "game10",
   "9" => "game2", "10" => "game3", "11" => "name3", "12" => "game4",
   "13" => "game10", "14" => "game2", "15" => "game3");
$narr = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr)/5; $i++)
   $narr[] = array_slice($arr, $i * 5, 5, true);
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(reset($a), reset($b));
}
uasort($narr, 'cmp');
print_r($narr);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => name1
            [2] => game4
            [3] => game10
            [4] => game2
            [5] => game3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [11] => name3
            [12] => game4
            [13] => game10
            [14] => game2
            [15] => game3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [6] => name4
            [7] => game4
            [8] => game10
            [9] => game2
            [10] => game3
        )
)
```

Comment: I want to sort my array by name ([1],[6],[11]

Comment: Above code is sorting the original array by elements `[1],[6],[11]` only. As you can original array had `name1, name4, name3` and sorted one has it as `name1, nam3, name4`.